# add a simple legend on ggplot with linetype

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

How do I add a legend to this ggplot? 
I've searched everywhere but couldn't find a simple way that matches my current code.
I've got three variable, they all have the same colour with different linetypes.

```
ggplot()+geom_line(data=datapop, aes(Year, OECD),size = 0.7, color="#69b3a2") +
    geom_line(data=datapop, aes(Year, World),size = 0.7, color="#69b3a2", linetype="dashed")+
    geom_line(data=datapop, aes(Year, Switzerland),size = 0.7, color="#69b3a2", linetype="twodash")+
    xlab("Years")+ ylab("Aging") +theme_minimal()+ labs(color="Legend text")+
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 years",date_labels = "%Y")+
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))
```

Comment: could you please provide some sample data in order to produce a reprex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Here is a solution with `mtcars`.

```
data("mtcars")

ggplot( data = mtcars) +
  geom_line(aes(gear, mpg, linetype = "mpg"), color = "royalblue", size = 0.7 ) + 
  geom_line(aes(gear, drat, linetype = "drat" ), color = "royalblue", size = 0.7 ) + 
  geom_line(aes(gear, qsec, linetype = "qsec" ), color = "royalblue",  size = 0.7 )+ 
  xlab("gear") + ylab("Outcomes") + 
  scale_linetype_manual( name = "Legend text", 
                         values = c( "mpg" = "solid",
                                     "drat" = "dashed",
                                     "qsec" = "twodash" ) ) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))
```

For you example, I would do the following. To adjust your `linetype` you should use `scale_linetype_manual()`. The argument `name` is for the legend's title, whereas `values` controls the linetype by calling the names you used in the original `aes()` within `geom_line()`.

```
ggplot( data = datapop)+
  geom_line(aes(Year, OECD, linetype = "OECD" ), color = "royalblue", size = 0.7 ) + 
  geom_line(aes(Year, World, linetype = "World" ), color = "royalblue", size = 0.7 ) + 
  geom_line(aes(Year, Switzerland, linetype = "Switzerland" ), color = "royalblue", size = 0.7 ) + 
  xlab("Year") + ylab("Aging") + 
  scale_color_manual( name = "Legend text",
                      values = c( "OECD" = "solid",
                                  "World" = "dashed",
                                  "Switzerland" = "twodash" ) ) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))
```

This is the way you should do it without using any other package rather than **ggplot2**.

Does it look better now?

Comment: almost good, problem is that the output in both of your examples is a legend with three same coloured lines and no linetype difference

Comment: That is because you passed in the same color which I though is what you wanted in the first place. You can apply the same strategy with the linetype.

Comment: I want to keep the same colour, but the three type of line should be differentiated in the legend. I'm not sure what to change to get that. Is it in scale_color or the color part in ass ?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be the `data.table` solution. Naturally, you first have to install and load the `data.table` package.

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)
```

I have created this dummy data for your situation, and converted the character type of 'Year' to the Date format, and converted whole data to a `data.table`:

```
datapop <- data.frame(Year = c("1980", "1982", "1984"), OECD = c(2,3,4), World = c(3,5,8), Switzerland = c(2,2.5,3)) %>% mutate(Year = as.Date(Year, format = "%Y")) %>% as.data.table()
```

I melted the these columns of 'OECD', 'World' and 'Switzerland' to a single column of 'variable' `data.table`'s `melt()` function, using 'Year' column as the ID column:

```
datapop_melted <- melt(datapop, id.vars = "Year")
```

Then, I simply plotted this data using `ggplot2` package. In the `aes()` section I have given `linetype = variable` argument, so that it creates the legend according to the line types by itself:

```
ggplot(data=datapop_melted) +
      geom_line(aes(x = Year, y = value, linetype = variable)) + 
      labs(title="Years vs Aging", x ="Years", y = "Aging", linetype = "Location") +
      scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 years", date_labels = "%Y") +
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1)) +
      theme_minimal()
```

You can see the resulting plot in the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afrBk.png).